# ls -S / ls -r Sorting on the command line (Bash) doesn't make sense

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, ls

I'm going through this tutorial on the command line. http://lifehacker.com/5633909/who-needs-a-mouse-learn-to-use-the-command-line-for-almost-anything

It mentioned I could type ls -S to sort the results by file size (I assumed it meant from largest to smallest) and that I could type ls -r to sort the results the other way (smallest to largest)

I immediately tried those commands on my home directory, but in both cases the same file tweets.csv was the first file listed.

Since tweets.csv can't possibly be both the largest file and the smallest file I'm very confused.

In case it helps in my home directory I have a bunch of other folders, and other file types such as another .csv, .txt, .py, .bash and .sh. I'm also running OSX El Captain version 10.11.1

So why don't ls -S and ls -r give me opposite results? Did I misunderstand them?

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Notice the command the list just under that? It is `ls -lSr`. See how that worked?

Answer (score 1):

`-r` reverses the sort order specified. If you don't specify any order, the files are sorted by name. `ls -r` sorts them by name, Z to A. To sort them by size from the largest to the smallest, use

```
ls -Sr
```

Adding `-l` will display file sizes, too, so you can verify the files are sorted  correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Two options need two letters:

```
ls -rS
```

To which you can add `long` to get:

```
ls -lrS
```

The order is usually of no impotance, so `-lrS` and `-rSl` mean the same, as using them split in separate values:

```
ls -r -S -l
```

That is, each option is activated by its presence.

You could sort by date, and use the `-r` to reverse the output:

```
ls -lc
ls -rlc
```